# Base of Global Call Stack in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, function, operating-system, callstack

I have read that each function invocation leads to **pushing of a stack frame in the global call stack** and once the function call is completed the call stack is popped off and the control passes to the address that we get from the popped of stack frame. If a called function calls on to yet another function, it will push another return address onto the top of the same call stack, and so on, with the information stacking up and unstacking as the program dictates.

I was wondering what's at the **base of global call stack** in a C or C++ program?

I did some searching on the internet but none of the sources explicitly mention about it. Is the call stack empty when our program starts and only once a function is called, the **call stack** usage starts? **OR** Is the address where `main()` function has to return, gets implicitly pushed as the base of our call stack and is a stack frame in our call stack? I expect the `main()` would also have a stack frame in our call stack since we are always returning something at end of our main() function and there needs to be some address to return to. **OR** is this dependent on compiler/OS and differs according to **implementation**?

It would be helpful if someone has some informative links about this or could provide details on the process that goes into it.

Comment: stack is not *global*. every thread have it own stack. and no any *global*. and this question unrelated to *c/c++*. this is pure os question.

Comment: @RbMm in multithreaded environment, that's true. But apart from that, there's only one global shared stack where all function call get their stack frame pushed into or popped off from.

Comment: again - no any global shared stack.stack is per thread. and unclear your question at all. for what you need base (top or low ?) address of stack memory region

Comment: @RbMm I Just wanted to know for knowledge purpose. It's not mentioned clearly about that which is why I asked it here. Also, unless we explicitly program to use multi-threading, a C program uses a single thread (correct me if I am wrong). So doesn't that mean that's there's only a single shared stack?

Comment: this is not language question.this is os (windows, linux, mac, etc) question. you need ask this with another tags i think. for me unclear what you mean under *shared* and *global*. and no such *C program*. say in windows exist processes. in every process exist several threads. every thread have it own stack. etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no such thing as a "global call stack". Each thread has a stack, and the stack for the main thread is often looking quite different from the thread of any thread spawned later on. And mostly, each of these "stacks" is just an arbitrary memory segment currently declared to be used as such, sub-allocated from any arbitrary suitable memory pool.

And due to compiler optimizations, many function calls will not even end up on the stack, usually. Meaning there isn't necessarily a distinguishable stack frame. You are only guaranteed that you can reference variables you put on the stack, but not that the compiler must preserve anything you didn't explicitly reference.

There is not even a guarantee that the memory layout for your call stack must even be organized in distinguishable frames. Function pointers are never guaranteed to be part of the stack frame, just happens to be an implementation detail in architectures where data and function pointers may co-exist in the address space. (As there are architectures which require return addresses to be stored in a different address space than the data used in the call stack.)

That aside, yes, there is code which is executed outside of the `main()` function. Specifically initializers for global `static` variables, code to set up the runtime environment (env, call parameters, stdin/stdout) etc.

E.g. when having linked to `libc`, there is `__libc_start_main` which will call your `main` function after initialization is done. And clean up when your `main` function returns.

`__libc_start_main` is about the point where "stack" starts being used, as far as you can see from within the program. That's not actually true though, there has already been some loader code been executed in kernel space, for reserving memory for your process to operate in initially (including memory for the future stack), initializing registers and memory to well defined values etc.

Right before actually "starting" your process, after dropping out of kernel mode, arbitrary pointers to a future stack, and the first instruction of your program, are loaded into the corresponding processor registers. Effectively, that's where `__libc_start_main` (or any other initialization function, depending on your runtime) starts running, and the stack visible to you starts building up.

Getting back into the kernel usually involves an interrupt now, which doesn't follow the stack either, but may just directly access processor registers to simply swap the contents of the corresponding processor registers. (E.g. if you call a function from the kernel, the memory required by the call stack inside the function call is not allocated from your stack, but from one you don't even have access to.)

Either way, everything that happens before `main()` is called, and whenever you enter a syscall, is implementation dependent, and you are not guaranteed any specific observable behavior. And messing around with processor registers, and thereby alternating the program flow, is also far outside defined behavior as far as a pure C / C++ run time is concerned.

Comment: Thanks, answers most of my question. Just to be sure, the usage of call stack is more of a system implementation side thing than rather than having the same behaviour in all c/cp programs, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a universal answer, as stack is something that may be implemented differently per architecture. For example a stack may grow up (i.e. stack position pointer value increases when pushing onto the stack) or grow downwards.

Exiting `main()` is usually done by calling an operating function to indicate the program wishes to to terminate (with the specified return code), so I don't expect a return address for `main()` to be present on the stack, but this may differ per operating system and even compiler.

I'm not sure why you need to know this, as this is typically something you leave up to the system.

Comment: Exit from `main()` is usually done by a clean return. And for `C++` environment, that's even the prerequisite for destructors of any `static` variables to run.

Comment: I was just curious since I wasn't able to find clearly about base of call stack. Your first point that this would be implementation based may be correct as per my guess. But it isn't mentioned anywhere clearly. Any source of info regarding this would be helpful

Comment: @Abhishek Details about how the stack works are more in the area of Assembler than C or C++. If you google something like `assembler how stack works` you may find more relevant thing like this:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/The_Stack

Answer (score 1):

main() is invoked by the libc code that handles setting up the environment for the executable etc. So by the time main() is called, the stack already has at least one frame created by the caller.

Comment: Is this the case in every system? or does it differ according to implementation/system. I didn't find a source mentioning it clearly, so my guess would be that it's upto implementation.

Comment: There is always some startup code before main() is called. This code is required to setup the stack, the process environment etc. But the exact nature of this startup code is implementation dependant. You can  read this for some good info: http://www.dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html

Answer (score 0):

Every system I have seen, when main() is called a stack is setup.  It has to be or just declaring a variable inside main would fail.  A stack is setup once a thread or process is created.  Thus any thread of execution has a stack.  Further in every assembly language i know, a register or fixed memory location is used to indicate the current value of the stack pointer, so the concept of a stack always exists (the stack pointer might be bad, but stack operations always exist since they are built into the every mainstream assembly language).